# How can I avoid string conversions when ingesting timestamps to postgres in Rust?

Tags: postgresql, rust, questdb

I'm using the [rust-postgres](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.19.0/postgres/) crate to ingest data. This is a working example adding rows successfully:

```rust
    let name: &str = "hello from rust";
    let val: i32 = 123;
    let now: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now();
    let timestamp = now.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.6f").to_string();
    client.execute(
        "INSERT INTO trades VALUES(to_timestamp($1, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSUUU'),$2,$3)",
        &[&timestamp, &name, &val],
    )?;
```

This doesn't look so nice as I have to do this forward and back string conversion, I would like to be able to write something like

```rust
    let name: &str = "hello from rust";
    let val: i32 = 123;
    let now: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now();
    client.execute(
        "INSERT INTO trades VALUES($1,$2,$3)",
        &[&now, &name, &val],
    )?;
```

What's the most performant way of ingesting timestamps in this way?

**Edit:**

Here's the returned error from the second example above

```sh
Error: Error { kind: ToSql(0), cause: Some(WrongType { postgres: Timestamp, rust: "chrono::datetime::DateTime<chrono::offset::utc::Utc>" }) }
```

And my `cargo.toml` looks like this (which has the chrono feature enabled for the rust postgres crate):

```
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.19"
postgres={version="0.19.0", features=["with-serde_json-1", "with-bit-vec-0_6", "with-chrono-0_4"]}
```

Comment: That depends on your DB schema, but maybe you can just store the unix timestamp of that (u64?).

Comment: This won't be a huge optimization though, DBMS itself would cause by far bigger latency than 2 extra string conversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Masklinn's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65828214/8836265), I needed to pass a `NaiveDateTime` type for this to work, the full example with `naive_local` looks like:

```rust
use postgres::{Client, NoTls, Error};
use chrono::{Utc};
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut client = Client::connect("postgresql://admin:quest@localhost:8812/qdb", NoTls)?;

    // Basic query
    client.batch_execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trades (ts TIMESTAMP, date DATE, name STRING, value INT) timestamp(ts);")?;

    // Parameterized query
    let name: &str = "rust example";
    let val: i32 = 123;
    let utc = Utc::now();
    let sys_time = SystemTime::now();
    client.execute(
        "INSERT INTO trades VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4)",
        &[&utc.naive_local(), &sys_time, &name, &val],
    )?;

    // Prepared statement
    let mut txn = client.transaction()?;
    let statement = txn.prepare("insert into trades values ($1,$2,$3,$4)")?;
    for value in 0..10 {
        let utc = Utc::now();
        let sys_time = SystemTime::now();
        txn.execute(&statement, &[&utc.naive_local(), &sys_time, &name, &value])?;
    }
    txn.commit()?;

    println!("import finished");
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a mismatch between your postgres schema and your Rust type: the error seems to say that your postgres type is `timestamp`, while your rust type is `DateTime<Utc>`.

If you check [the conversion table](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.0/tokio_postgres/types/trait.ToSql.html), `DateTime<Utc>` converts to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. The only types which convert to `TIMESTAMP` are `NaiveDateTime` and `PrimitiveDateTime`.

Comment: So something along these lines should work where `utc = Utc::now();`  and I'm inserting `&[&utc.naive_local(), &_name, &_val]`?

Comment: I haven't use chrono much but I'd guess, or change the schema to store a timestamptz.